# Query to sum by same value in one column and filter by unique values in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Came across a SQL query problem as below:

```
Id, Val1, Val2, Lat,  Lon
1,  10.1, 20.3, 30.5, 120.3
2,  12.4, 15.7, 25.3, 110.7
3,  10.1, 24.5, 27.8, 115.0
4,  10.1, 18.9, 25.3, 110.7
```

Get the sum(Val2) for rows which match Val1, but have a unique Lat, Lon with no match with any other row. The result in this example would be 20.3(row1) + 24.5(row 3) = 44.8. Row 4 is ignored as it's Lat, Lon matches with row 2.

What would be the query to return the sum in this case?

Comment: @Eric And what exactly have you done?

Answer (score 2):

This query should give you your desired results. It `SUM`s `Val2` for each `Val1` as long as no matching `Lat` and `Lon` values are found for another value of `Id`:

```
SELECT Val1, COALESCE(SUM(Val2), 0) AS "Sum"
FROM data d
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                 FROM data d1
                 WHERE d1.Id != d.Id AND d1.Lat = d.Lat AND d1.Lon = d.Lon)
GROUP BY Val1
```

Output

```
Val1    Sum
10.1    44.8
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=78e5301dcf532b361aecadf5a4c49512)

Comment: I think `id` is a more apt comparison for the correlation clause than `val1`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yeah, on re-reading I think you're probably right. I have edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below option-

[Demo Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e937c50b106698e26e1d098b1cdf4d35)

```
SELECT SUM(Val2) 
FROM your_table
WHERE CAST(Lat AS VARCHAR)+CAST(Lon AS VARCHAR) IN
(
    SELECT CAST(Lat AS VARCHAR)+CAST(Lon AS VARCHAR)
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY Lat,Lon
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd approach the problem:

Set up the data:

```
drop table if exists #t
create table #t (id int, val1 numeric(4, 1), val2 numeric(4, 1), lat numeric(4, 1), lon numeric(4, 1))
insert #t (Id, Val1, Val2, Lat, Lon) 
values 
(1, 10.1, 20.3, 30.5, 120.3),
(2, 12.4, 15.7, 25.3, 110.7),
(3, 10.1, 24.5, 27.8, 115.0),
(4, 10.1, 18.9, 25.3, 110.7)
```

And do the actual query:

```
select sum(val2)
  from #t t
  left join (select lat, lon
              from #t
             group by lat, lon
            having count(*) > 1) u
   on t.lat = u.lat
  and t.lon = u.lon
 where u.lat is null
```